# What is an easy way to transform an equality into a replacement rule?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I found the necessity for the following procedure and was surprised I couldn't find a built-in function to do the following. I include my solution in case someone needs the same functionality, but if there exists a built in feature that I'm not aware of please feel free to share.

Suppose using `Reduce`, I have created a set of conditions for a system of equations:

```
(a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0)
```

What is an easy way to convert these equalities into a set of replacement rules so that they may be inserted back into an equation?

```
a + b x + c x^2
```

I.e., what is a method for converting the set of conditions shown above into the following form?

```
{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 0}
```

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I seem to have a bad habit of consistently write inequality instead of equality :D

Comment: I think we have 10 ways of doing it by now :-)

Comment: That should do for now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With:

```
eqns = (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0)
```

Just use a built-in function:

```
ToRules[eqns]
```

> `{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 0}`

---

If, however, you want to do the same using list processing:

```
TreeForm /@ {eqns, Rule @@@ List @@ eqns}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha! Brilliant, there is a built-in function for that.

Answer (score 8):

I expect there will be many solutions, probably the best alternative is to use [`ToRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html), as suggested by @Syed.

Anyhow, here I present you with two other simple ways.

## ReplaceAll

If you understand the internal representation ([`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html)) of your list, by looking at

```
FullForm[(a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0)]
(* And[Equal[a,1],Equal[b,2],Equal[c,0]] *)
```

then you could use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
ReplaceAll[
   (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0)
   ,{And->List,Equal->Rule}
]
(* {a->1,b->2,c->0}  *)
```

## Solve

Another option would be to just [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) it

```
Solve[(a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0)]
(* {{a->1,b->2,c->0}}  *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is the following:

```
ReplaceAll[Equal -> Rule][Level[eqns, {1}]]
(*{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 0}*)
```

Comment: Hello there 10-ways team :)

Comment: Hi @bmf, the ten ways team is active :)

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html). It uses the same idea that @rhermans suggested as you see; it redefines [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html?q=List) and [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html).

```
rules = Block[{And = List, Equal = Rule}, eqns]
```

> [image: block]

Answer (score 5):

My method was to simply use a table to iterate over each element of the collection of equality and re-write them as a replacement rule:

```
cond = (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0)
rule = Table [ cond[[i, 1]] -> cond[[i, 2]], {i, Length[cond]}]
a + b x + c x^2 /. rule
(* 1 + 2 x *)
```

Which works well to give the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Since we did all the normal ways, the following is fun.

Extract the values and the parameters from the output of [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) using [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) and [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and then [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) to create a list of rules:

```
eqns = (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0);

values = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 2]]];
var = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 1]]];

Thread[var -> #] &@values
```

> [image: thread]

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, one can go about it in the following manner:

```
eqns = (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0);
values = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 2]]];
var = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 1]]];
Rule @@@ Transpose@{var, values}
```

> [image: res]

Answer (score 3):

Another way of obtaining the desired output is:

```
eqns = (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0);
values = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 2]]];
var = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 1]]];
Inner[Rule, var, values, List]
```

> [image: output]

Answer (score 3):

The following also works:

```
eqns = (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 0);
values = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 2]]];
var = Apply[List, eqns[[All, 1]]];
# -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{var, values}]
```

> [image: res]