# How to replace==in the equation with ->?

Tags: equation-solving

It is required to replace the   `==`

in equation

`2b==E ^ x0- x0`

with `->`,

becoming:

`2b ->E ^ x0- x0`

My personal attempt was like this, but it didn't achieve the goal

```
eq1 = E^x0 - x0 - 2 b == 0
eq2 = eq1 /. k_ + m_ - 2 b == 0 :> 2 b == k + m
eq3 = eq2 /. Thread["==" -> "->"]
```

Comment: `Solve[E^x0 - x0 - 2 b == 0 /. b -> b/2, b] /. b -> 2*b // 
  Flatten // First `

Comment: `2 b == E^x0 - x0 /. Equal -> Rule`

Comment: Why is `ToRules` not an option?

Comment: MMA 13.3 ToRules works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an easy way to transform an equality into a replacement rule?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267337/what-is-an-easy-way-to-transform-an-equality-into-a-replacement-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations

```
eq = 2 b == E^x0 - x0;
```

The `Head` of `eq` is `Equal`

```
Head @ eq
```

Equal

The `Head` is always at position 0

```
ps = Position[Equal] @ eq
```

{{0}}

Therefore we must `ReplaceAt` position 0

```
ReplaceAt[eq, _ :> Rule, ps]
```

2*b -> E^x0 - x0

or use `ReplaceAll` like Syed suggested in his commentary.

We can also use `ToRules`:

```
First @ ToRules @ eq
```

2*b -> E^x0 - x0

or `Apply` with its third argument:

```
Apply[Rule, eq, {0}]
```

2*b -> E^x0 - x0

**Addendum**

Like `lericr` mentioned in his comment, `Apply` doesn't need the third argument in this case and can also be written as:

```
Apply[Rule, eq];
```

or

```
Apply[Rule] @ eq
```

or

```
Rule @@ eq
```

Comment: The default levelspec is sufficient: `Apply[Rule, eq]`. Special form: `Rule @@ eq`.

Comment: Thank you, I added your comment to the answer