How to convert the form of the Solve solution to the form of the Reduce solution
{tanx -> 1/Sqrt[2], tanx -> -Sqrt[2]}
How to convert the form of the solve solution above to the form of the reduce solution
tanx == 1/Sqrt[2] || tanx == -Sqrt[2]

(-1) I don't see your effort to understand the answers you've obtained: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/290758/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/301216/1871

You can do it in 2 steps. First replace Rule by == and then change the head to Or
e1 = {tanx -> 1/Sqrt[2], tanx -> -Sqrt[2]}
e1 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> a == b
Or @@ %



One way could be:
sol = {tanx -> 1/Sqrt[2], tanx -> -Sqrt[2]}

Or @@ Equal @@@ List @@@ sol

or
Apply[Or]@Map[Apply[Equal]]@Map[Apply[List]][sol]



tanx == 1/Sqrt[2] || tanx == -Sqrt[2]

